# Firebase Realtime Database with Unity. Only want to fetch the latest added children under a specific node. (Not fetch the older ones)

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Realtime Database to save some some links under a parent called - Links.

Let's say there are 5 links and my app fetched them. And after few days I added 5 more. How can I make my app only check the latest 5 ones added and not the previous ones ?

I have use OnValueChanged, ChildAdded, Child Removed etc. Nothing works the way I want. It checks all the children under Links which is wastage of bandwidth.

I specifically want my app to only fetch the updated or new ones.

I am using it with Unity. Any suggestions, please ?

Answer (score 0):

Generate a reference per link and push them individually

Firebase's `Push` method to generate a time based key for each link as follows:

```
var linksParent = Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase.GetReference("linksParent");

var newLinks = new List<string>(){"somelink","otherLink","anotherLink","yetAnother", "lastLink"};

foreach(var link in links)
{
   var linkRef = linksParent.Push(); // Generates a time based key for this reference.
   linkRef.SetValueAsync(link);
}
```

To retrieve the latest 5 links, since they're stored lexicographically in the database by the time they were inserted.

```
var linksParent = Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase.GetReference("linksParent");
// Retrieve the most recent 5 links, if there's less than 5 in the list, it'll fetch them all.
linksParent.LimitToLast(5).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task=>
{
   if(task.IsCompleted)
   {
      // Yes there are links and we fetched the latest.
      if(task.Result.Exists) 
      {
          // Do something with your links at task.Result.
      }
   }
});
```

You can also listen to the links list and fetch the latest 5 every time the list changes

```
var linksParent = Firebase.Database.FirebaseDatabase.GetReference("linksParent");
linksParent.LimitToLast(5).ValueChanged += OnLinksChanged;

void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) 
{
      if (args.DatabaseError != null) 
      {
        Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
        return;
      }
      // Do something with the links in args.Snapshot
}
```